# How to remove a ceramic lightbulb socket

Tags: electrical, light-bulb

I have an industrial style floor lamp from Restoration Hardware. The light socket broke (see images). I’m trying to remove the ceramic light socket piece as described here
[How to fix the metal part of socket?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/204750/how-to-fix-the-metal-part-of-socket?newreg=746e2a2ab9e74c6493d7209f2b51f38d)

But unable to do so ie I have tried to pull it out after taking as much as I can apart but it does not come out. Any ideas on how to replace it? A shame to let it go to waste :(
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "unable to do so" mean, exactly. One would think a good start would be to undo the 3 screws shown in your photo to get to the bottom of the socket.

Comment: I had unscrewed those three screws but they turned out to be unrelated to the socket. The ceramic piece remains stuck. I cannot seem to pull it out

Comment: There is a way to get it apart. The 3 screws my have more to do with it than you realize. Without pictures of the rear of the lamp to show where possible joints are, or closeups of the sides, it will be difficult to figure how it comes apart. Without no more than what I see here, the back of the lamp is how the socket is accessed for removal. The ventilated end usually is a separate piece held in place by the socket cover and the nut on the end, which happens to look like a small cone with a brass ring around it, attached to the ball joint.

Comment: I can't tell for sure from your photo but are there two screws in the bottom of the socket? Those would be what's holding it in.

Comment: You have to undo the screws  which allow the socket to be pushed. And you have to undo the back of the lamp to remove it all. Only you are there, so try turning everything imaginable

Comment: those usually have a small metal "L" bracket riveted to the outside of the porcelain. You should be able to reach it once the reflector is removed by the 3 screws. It's likely also riveted to the lamp itself, so you'll have to drill out the rivet to replace. If you can't re-rivet it, some JB weld can be used to attach the new socket.

Comment: Oh boy thanks all - I have unscrewed everything I can and still no luck. The area where the lamp connects to that piece with all the holes seems to turn around but I cannot seem to unscrew it out. It just turns and turns in place with no visible outcome. @dandavis how would I drill  out the rivet?

Comment: Oh, first time, fun. Find a drill bit slightly smaller than the rivet and just drill baby drill; light pressure and patience; it will take a little bit, but you should feel it give when it does. If there's a small crescent of metal still attached, you can usually just yank the part/bracket and the rivet will fall to pieces.